# Highlight All Cells in a Row Varying Colors Based on Multiple Cell Entries

Tags: excel, vba

Apologies for the confusing title. What I am attempting is not too difficult (I think). I am attempting to fill in entire rows of a spreadsheet based on values entered into specific cells of those rows. For example: I would like to fill in the row to be blue if the K value of that row is equal to 2. I have been able to get this far using the code below.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("K:K")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Target.Value <> "2" Then Exit Sub
Target.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
MsgBox "2nd First Article Build. Notify Quality Techs to Create Fixture "
End Sub
```

I would like to take this a step further and fill in the row to be green when "yes" is entered as the L value. So far all my attempts at this are returning error messages or being accepted but not returning anything when "Yes" is entered into the L cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one `Worksheet_Change` event per sheet so you will need to pack everything into one sub.

1. If more than 1 cell triggered the macro `Exit Sub`. An example of multiple cells triggering the macro is clearing the contents of a range larger than one cell.
2. Expand your `Intersect` to allow for Columns `K:L`
3. Determine which column triggered the macro via `Select Case` where `Column K = Column 7` and `Column L = Column 8`
4. Do not test for the absence of 2 (as your current code does). Instead, just see if the value is 2. This means you do not have to `Exit Sub` mid procedure.
5. Kudos to you for having `Option Explicit` **:)**

---

If is worth nothing that your conditions are set up to potentially overwrite the other.
 What happens when `K = 2` & `L = Yes` on the same row? Whichever cell was most recently changed will take precedence. If you have not given this any consideration, you will need to assign precedence to one of your criteria.

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K:L")) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Column
        Case 7
            If Target = 2 Then Target.EntireRow.Interior.Color = ####

        Case 8
            If Target = "Yes" Then Target.EntireRow.Interior.Color = ####
    End Select
End If

End Sub
```